AppShell - positioning menu items towards the end of the page
I have a simple AppShell menu and would like to position the Logout option towards the end of the page. I tried using a MenuFlyoutSeparator but I feel like that leaves some distinct space but may differ in devices with different heights so it won't be exact.
How would I position the Logout towards the bottom? Maybe right above the FlyoutFooter
  <FlyoutItem Title="Students" Icon="student">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Students:StudentsPage}" Route="StudentsPage" />
  </FlyoutItem>
  <FlyoutItem Title="Teachers" Icon="teacher">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Teachers:TeachersPage}" Route="TeachersPage" />
  </FlyoutItem>
  <FlyoutItem Title="Staff" Icon="staff">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Staff:SStaffPage}" Route="StaffPage" />
  </FlyoutItem>

  <MenuFlyoutSeparator></MenuFlyoutSeparator>
  <MenuFlyoutSeparator></MenuFlyoutSeparator>
  <MenuFlyoutSeparator></MenuFlyoutSeparator>

  <MenuItem Text="Logout" IconImageSource="logout"></MenuItem>


You can take the Logout as the Shell.FlyoutFooter.
Specifically, FlyoutFooter will always appear at the bottom of the flyout, with its appearance being defined by an object that can be set with the Shell.FlyoutFooter bindable property.
Here I set the FlyoutFooter to ContentView as an example:
AppShell.xaml:
<Shell ...>
    <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
        <controls:FlyoutFooter />
    </Shell.FlyoutFooter>
</Shell>

FlyoutFooter.xaml:
<ContentView ...>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Logout" clicked=""/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>

You can freely define the appearance of the Logout in the ContentView, you can refer to Flyout footer for more details.

this is not ideal as FlyoutFooter doesn't next FlyoutItems. I have an item as so:   



Do you mean you want to set the settings FlyoutItem at the end of the flyout?

Yes correct. The logout was just an example. I want to set a few fly out items and menu items positioned at the bottom of the screen

This needs a specific number. What kind of style do you want at the bottom of the flyout? How many FlyoutItems? How many MenuItems?

ok, let's say two flyoutitems and two menuitems.

I'm testing this requirement

According to the description in the documentation, the footer can be fixed at the bottom of the flyout, and the contentview of the footer can be set to an icon plus a label to form a similar appearance to the flyoutitem, is that acceptable to you?

That’s going back to creating custom label and icon. I want to use the flyoutitem and menuitem
